# ASP Classic Snippets in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vbscript, asp-classic

How I should create asp classic snippets and use they in visual studio? I follow some tutorials on the internet but doesn't work at all:

This is a sample from my snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Total de registros a serem exportados.</Title>
            <Author>Lucas Luan de Melo Pereira</Author>
            <Description>Implementa a busca ao parametro de limite de linhas a serem exportadas.</Description>
            <Shortcut>snpTot</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="VBScript">
                <![CDATA[
                    '---------Total de registros a serem exportados---------------
                    response.write("Awesome feature!")
                    '-------------------------------------------------------------
                ]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

In VS, I'm importing inside VB option (Code Snippets Manager). But when try to use don't work also another question, this will be called by Intellisense? There's no option of snippets im my *.asp files.

Comment: An alternative method is to highlight your snippets in the VS editor and drag them to the Toolbox; you can then rename them, if desired. Then, when you need them in your code, you do the opposite: drag them from the Toolbox to the line of your code where you want to plop them.